# What does @$_GET mean?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why someone is using the @ in the code, I have seen it with mysql connections but I don't know what it means.. thanks!

```
$player_name_orig = @$_GET['player'];
if (!$player_name_orig) {
    die('You must specify a player name');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The @ is the [error suppression operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

In this specific context, it's a (wrong!) way to avoid PHP giving a notice if the `player` key does not exist in `$_GET`:

If you try this:

```
unset($_GET['player']); // to make sure
echo $_GET['player'];
```

You get:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: player in F:\dev\www\index.php on line **35**

While if you try this:

```
unset($_GET['player']); // to make sure
echo @$_GET['player'];
```

There is no output.

**The correct way to do this:**

```
if (empty($_GET['player']) {
    die('You must specify a player name');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@` will stop any errors from appearing and return false on an error.

So in your code if `$_GET['player']` does not exist then the code will go into the if statement

Answer (score 2):

@ Means to ignore errors such as the variable not being set.

Answer (score 0):

the "@" is used to prevent any warning or error message to appear. It's a really bad habit. Doing that a lot of hidden operations are done (removing error handler, and putting it back after).

The right way to do that operation is:

```
// my_security_filter() is a function that can render FALSE and remove any dangerous thing
$player_name_orig = array_key_exists('player',$_GET)? my_security_filter($_GET['player']) : FALSE;
if (FALSE===$player_name_orig) { ...
```